# cannot remove child from Cocos2D CCNode

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a CCLayer.

I create a CCNode* from another function, return it and add it to the CCLayer.

When I ret to remove it bu tag however I am told it doesn't exist

```
cocos2d::CCNode* Class::function() 
{
    cocos2d::CCNode* n = cocos2d::CCNode::create()
    ... I add stuff to it....
    node->setTag(9);
    return node;
}
```

Then elsewhere I do:

```
mynode = Class::function();
    addChild(mynode, 3);
```

and when ready to remove:

```
removeChildByTag(9);
```

I am told that the child doesn't exist

I even tried

```
mynode = Class::function();
    mynode->setTag(9);
    addChild(mynode, 3);
```

and when ready to remove:

```
removeChildByTag(9);
```

I am told that the child doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You need to retain your Node in the function you are calling otherwise the node you are creating will be automatically removed from the Auto-release Pool after function execution.

```
cocos2d::CCNode* n = cocos2d::CCNode::create()
n->retain();
```

Comment: Does it matter where I retain() though? just before I return it?

Comment: and just to be sure, I have to retain even though I am returning the `CCNode`?